# How is 2 Maccab 12 :42-44 interpreted by denominations not accepting the existence of purgatory?

Tags: 2-maccabees, purgatory

We read in 2 Maccab 12: 42-44:

> Then, Judas, that great man, urged the people to keep away from sin, because they had seen for themselves what had happened to those men who had sinned.  He also took up a collection from all his men, totaling about four pounds of silver, and sent it to Jerusalem to provide for a sin offering. Judas did this noble thing because he believed in the resurrection of the dead.  If he had not believed that the dead would be raised, it would have been foolish and useless to pray for them.

Denominations like Catholicism that believe in the existence of purgatory quote this OT reference in support of the belief. One would be interested to know how the other denominations interpret the verses.

Comment: I suggest this question would be better on SE-C as it is not an hermeneutic matter but a matter of denominational interpretation.

Comment: I cannot see any connection at all with purgatory here.  Perhaps this might be better on CSX.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Christianity SX.